# Azure Function Multiple Job Hosts

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am experiencing a strange problem with Azure Functions that is starting up multiple job hosts.  The initial host seems to startup and subsequent hosts error trying to acquire singleton lock. It is really noticeable when I disable one of the jobs and the error message appears that the "function runtime is unable to start". I noticed that my timer triggers were executing multiple times per their configuration "0 */30 * * * *" which caused me to dig deeper into this situation.

```
Pid 1 2017-04-25T13:30:06.680 Staging table updated successfully.
Pid 1 2017-04-25T13:30:06.680 Updating the base table from the staging table.
Pid 2 2017-04-25T13:30:06.680 Staging table updated successfully.
Pid 2 2017-04-25T13:30:06.680 Updating the base table from the staging table.
```

Details about the Function App:
- Azure Function running under the Dynamic/Consumption plan
- 5 functions running from class libraries (followed this guide - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/)
- 2 functions are executed from a timer, every 30 minutes  "0 */30 * * * *"
- 1 timer trigger disabled while waiting for development time
- 1 blob trigger watching a container for uploads from IoT Hub
- 1 EventHub trigger receiving events from IoT Hub (sparse events so no heavy load here)

Steps to reproduce:
- Stand up Azure function with Dynamic plan
- Create the Azure functions in the portal (ran into issues not doing this prior)
- Deploy the functions from VSTS, using WebDeploy from the guide above
- Make sure the functions tried to start
- Disable one of the functions to force a restart
- Error messages start displaying

Log pulled from the Function:
[Link to log file](https://acuitybrandsinc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/jsk03_acuitysso_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=0f6ec7b7ebf5549d086ad3d400c8e6c8e&authkey=AbmLFDKAFIBvUSO7O_rh1mg)

I have stopped the Azure Function App Service, removed the lock folder to see if that helps acquire singleton locks which it does, but as soon as a function is enabled/disabled or pushed from VSTS using the web deploy the errors return. I have rebuilt the Azure Function a couple of times and the outcome is still the same.

We are in the process of trying to understand how to troubleshoot this issue so we can create a monitoring process around this scenario.

**Edit**
The function that executed twice is setup with the following (all of the functions look very similar to this):
function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\IngestionFunctionClassLibrary.dll",
  "entryPoint": "IngestionFunctionClassLibrary.Functions.AnalyticsUpdate.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger", 
      "direction": "in",
          "schedule": "0 */30 * * * *"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": true`
}
```

project.json

```
{
  "frameworks": {
    "net46":{
      "dependencies": {
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the Azure function implementation is not relevant? You did not post that part.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I have updated to include the function definition for the one that I have seen run multiples.

Comment: Please update question title to reflect what the issue is, as just having "Azure Function Multiple Job Hosts" does not convey that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages that look like *Unable to acquire Singleton lock* are actually not errors, but simply informational messages. What it means that your Function App was scaled out to multiple instances (in your case about 5). There are some lease resources that can intrinsically only be held by one instance (to support singleton behavior). So once an instance gets the lease, all others will display this message.